# jq - extract multiple fields from a list, with a nested list of key/value pairs

Tags: jq

I have the following structure:

```json
{
  "Subnets": [
    {
      "SubnetId": "foo1",
      "Id": "bar1",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "foo"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Status",
          "Value": "dev"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "SubnetId": "foo2",
      "Id": "bar2",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "foo"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Status",
          "Value": "dev"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can extract multiple keys at the "top level" like so:

```
cat subnets.json| jq '.Subnets[] | "\(.Id) \(.SubnetId)"'
```

Anyone know how I can also display one of the tags by key name, let's say I also want the Status tag displayed on the same line as the Id and SubnetId.

Thx for any help,

Comment: You don't need `cat` here, just give your JSON file as parameter to `jq` like so: `jq '...' subnets.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
jq '.Subnets[] | "\(.Id) \(.SubnetId) \(.Tags | from_entries | .Status)"' subnets.json
```

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I was looking for. Much thx!